# Is it possible to get element from webpage?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

In my program, I'm using webbrowser (C#) and I want to get all element from the current page to text. Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
HtmlElement htmlelement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("html");
if (htmlelement == null)
{
}
else
{
    richTextBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("html").OuterText;
}
```

Ps. OuterHtml can use on this?

Comment: Please include code so far.

Comment: I'm no code right now cause I'm out of any idea.
But in Webbrowser its name webBrowser1 
and I want all element in current webpage.  (Just like you press F12 on website and see it. Is it call inspector?) and then I want them to show in richTextBox1
That's it~~

Comment: Come back to the question when you have code. As it stands, the question is too broad, and an answer would be too long for SO.

Comment: @techydesigner 

Before I'm out of Idea, I'm using this

HtmlElement htmlelement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("html");
            if (htmlelement == null)
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("html").OuterText;
            }
            
But it's nothing.

Comment: Please incorporate extra information into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.example.com/");
HtmlNodeCollection tags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tag1//tag2");
```

Comment: Also take a look to nice tutorial: [Parsing Html with Web Browser Control](http://www.swhistlesoft.com/blog/2012/12/21/1689-parsing-html-with-web-browser-control)

Comment: Now, I have figure out from this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502968/net-webbrowser-firebug-style-inspect-html-element

Thank you all to make a comments :D

Answer (score 0):

In Java i use the below code, some reformating should fetch you C# code.

```
List<WebElement> webPageElements = driver.findElementsByTagName(webHTMLTagName);
// Loop Over All WebPage Elements with same Tag Type
for (WebElement webElement : webPageElements) {
        System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("type"));
        System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("name"));
        System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

webHTMLTagName can be your html tag.(for eg., "input")